Checking an error in a Differential Geometry problem on curvature and diffeomorphism types of compact surfaces
I am currently working through the following old exam problem.

I have reached part (d)(i) but I believe the result required still is not guaranteed even with the new hypotheses.
For example, if we take $S_n$ to alternate between fixed standard copies of a sphere and a torus in $\mathbb R^3,$ then it is clear that (1)-(4) hold (by standard compactness arguments and direct constructions of geodesic polar coordinates on these familiar surfaces), however, here $\inf_{x \in S_n} K_n (x)$ will alternate between a fixed pair of positive and negative values, and so the $\limsup$ of these values will certainly be positive.
Here it is not the case that the $S_n$ are eventually diffeomorphic to $S^2$ at all.
Is this indeed an error or is there some detail I am missing?
I have an argument for this part that works if $\limsup$ is replaced by $\liminf$.

Yes, they have made a mistake. You should complain.
